# Read Serial port data using node js

Tags: node.js, express, npm, serial-port

I want to read data from serial port and get from data when reqested

Here is my code

```
const http = require('http');
const hostname = 'localhost';
const { SerialPort } = require('serialport')
const { ReadlineParser } = require('@serialport/parser-readline')
const { io } = require('socket.io');
let express = require('express')

const serialPort = new SerialPort({ 
    path: 'COM4',
    baudRate: 9600 ,
})
const parser = serialPort.pipe(new ReadlineParser({ delimiter: '\r\n' }))
let app = express();
var port = 8080;

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
app.get('/get_data', function(req, res) {
    parser.on('data', function(data) {
        res.json({'weight': data});
    });
});
```

When i am try to get data i got ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
I want serial port data when requested from localhost:8080/get_data anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data event from `parser` is probably firing more than once, which means you would be calling `res.json` more than once. As you can see in the [express api documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json), `res.json` sets the `content-type` header...thus you can only call it once per request. Hence the error.

What I think would normally be done in this kind of situation is to set up a queuing system. A simple version might be done using an array, although if you were using this in a production server it might be better to use a proper message queuing system (e.g. rabbitMQ, kafka, AWS SQS, etc).

Here's an example of how you might use an array:

```
const queue = [];
parser.on('data', function(data) {
  // push new data onto end of queue (array)
  queue.push(data);
});
app.get('/get_data', function(req, res) {
  if (req.params.getFullQueue === 1) {
    // empty complete contents of current queue,
    // sent to client as an array of { weight: x } objects
    const data = queue.splice(0, queue.length)
      .map(x => ({ weight: x }));
    res.json(data);
  } else {
    // get oldest enqueued item, send it only
    res.json({ weight: queue.shift() });
  }
});
```

The `if/else` in the `app.get` is meant to illustrate these two options, depending on which you wanted to use. In production you'd probably want to implement pagination, or maybe even a websocket or EventSource so that data could be pushed as it became available.

Comment: Thanks for the hep, it work well, but there is one issue, when i disconnect the port it will return old data returning from serial port, can we fix it ?

Comment: Sure...looks like there is an [close event](https://serialport.io/docs/api-stream#close) in the docs, you can just a handler to that event to empty the queue when that happens.

Comment: Can i check port is connected or not in the app.get() ?

Comment: I need only last data returned from serial port.